# Entity Framework Inserting child record with parent knowing

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have this problem where I am inserting a child record and in the database the navigation column is `null` instead of referencing the parents `Id`.

How can I fix this?

There will only ever be 1 record in the `AdminConfiguration` Table

**Model**

```
public class AdminConfiguration : Entity
{
    public virtual List<ApplicationConfiguration> ApplicationConfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

**Child**

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : Entity
{
    public Applications Application { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string HttpScheme { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Insert code**

```
public ApplicationConfiguration Insert(ApplicationConfiguration entity)
{
    Db.ApplicationConfiguration.Add(entity);
    Db.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

What the DB looks like after insert:

```
ID | Other columns | AdminConfiguration_Id
1  | Other values  | NULL
```

Comment: You have no foreign key or navigation property on your `ApplicationConfiguration` entity so how can EF possibly know which `AdminConfiguration` record it relates to.

Comment: When I insert the `AdminConfiguration` record it created the extra Column, I thought it just would automatically use that., not sure how though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an appropriate navigation property on your ApplicationConfiguration entity so EF can map the relationship, personally I would also create a foreign key property as below, as it often easier to just specify the related entity ID rather than having to populate the navigation property.

```
public class ApplicationConfiguration : Entity
{
    public Applications Application { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string HttpScheme { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual AdminConfiguration AdminConfiguration { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AdminConfiguration")]
    public int AdminConfigurationId { get; set; }
}
```

This will get rid of the `AdminConfiguration_Id` column and instead create a `AdminConfigurationId` columns that will map to the property on your class.

Comment: why did you add `  public AdminConfiguration AdminConfiguration { get; set; }` into the class?

Comment: @JamieRees It is the corresponding navigation property for the other end of the relationship, i.e. it contains the `AdminConfiguration` entity that the given `ApplicationConfiguration` entity relates to.

Comment: @JamieRees if you use LazyLoading (I think you do) mark as virtual also Application property or EF won't retrieve it.